# Iterating over Cartesian product is slow

Tags: julia

using `product` from [Iterator.jl](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/Iterators.jl) one can can iterate over all combinations in the Cartesian product of the inputs. However, it turns it to be much slower than just "brute forcing it":

```
using Iterators

@time(
for tup in product(-100:100, -100:100, -100:100)
    # do something with silly tup
    maximum(tup)
end
)
# 10.033157 seconds (64.97 M allocations: 3.510 GB, 3.03% gc time)
```

A straight forward nested loop:

```
@time(
for x in -100:100, y in -100:100, z in -100:100
    # do something silly with x, y, z
    maximum([x y z])
end
)
# 0.420949 seconds (8.12 M allocations: 867.374 MB, 4.31% gc time)
```

Does anyone know why? (using the iterator returned from `product` would lead to simpler code down the block, allowing one to for ex `pmap` over a large Cartesian grid. Using Julia `v"0.5.1"`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of the functions in Iterators.jl are now built into Julia's `Base.Iterators` module in version 0.6.  Instead of `using Iterators`, you can use the version in `Base.Iterators` instead:

```
julia> @time(
       for tup in product(-100:100, -100:100, -100:100)
           # do something with silly tup
           maximum(tup)
       end
       )
 18.110503 seconds (64.98 M allocations: 3.510 GiB, 3.32% gc time)

julia> @time(
       for tup in Base.Iterators.product(-100:100, -100:100, -100:100)
           # do something with silly tup
           maximum(tup)
       end
       )
  0.658809 seconds (8.12 M allocations: 247.821 MiB, 5.50% gc time)
```

It's not significantly affecting this result, but in general you shouldn't benchmark at global scope since it's not representative of how you run typical programs in Julia.  Wrap the code inside a function, instead.

You can look at [the difference](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/Iterators.jl/blob/171aa9952e0588948393abbf43ea52b8d8537550/src/Iterators.jl#L217-L280) [in implementations](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/4a814806811d13b350a3f6c04cb839ad4c9236f1/base/iterators.jl#L531-L658) if you're curious about how the two are different.  Base's implementation is highly optimized since it's used in many core structures (like comprehensions and generators).  There are many reasons the Iterators.jl implementation is slow, including those `copy` calls, using unspecialized `Any[]` vectors, and a type instability in `state[2]`.

Comment: Thanks alot, but in this particular example I didn't think there was any difference between timing in global scope and within a typed function...? (or am I missing something?)

Comment: Yup, that's just a caution for the future since it can lead to confusing results that aren't generally applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Well your time output tells you as much:

64.97M allocations for the `product()` chewing through something like 3.5GB of memory; versus 8.12M allocations eating 'only' 867MB.

Memory allocations are slow. If you have an order of magnitude more allocations and an order of magnitude bigger allocations to worry about, that is going to slow you down.

Comment: thanks, I kind of thought it was implicit that memory allocation was the culprit, the question is why an iterator, which is supposed to be efficient, demands this much memory... :) Sorry if not being clear.

Comment: Ah, well if you look at what Iterator.jl does at lines 245 thru 280... There's lots and lots of copying going to be involved.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should have asked about this on their github repo instead.

Comment: I think the memory allocations are substantial in both case because you are using global variables and measuring code in global scope.